# SSH and send commands in Tkinter?

Tags: python, ssh, tkinter, tcl, expect

I'm trying to convert code from TCL into python using Tkinter.
I was wondering what would be the equivalent code in Tkinter for 
"spawn ssh", "expect", and "send"?
For example, my simple tcl program would be something like:

```
spawn ssh root@138.120.###.###
expect "(yes/no)?" {send -- "yes\r"}
expect "password" {send -- "thepassword\r"}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or does this have nothing to do with `Tkinter`?

Comment: You are missing the first part "I'm trying to convert code from TCL into python using Tkinter."

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: Yes, but this really has to do with interacting with shell commands, right?  Tkinter is about the gui, and there is no gui here.  It seems an extraneous detail.  The reason this matters is that many people will not look at questions for gui toolkits that they do not know.  He's inadvertantly limiting the population of answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).

Expect is used to automate other command line tools.

Edit: Of curse you could just try to execute `package require Expect` through Tkinter, but what benefit would that have over a pure Tcl script? After all you write Tcl code then, wraped in python.

Another Edit: Tkinter is used to get access to Tk (the cool GUI Toolkit :P) from python, and it works by calling Tcl commands somewhere down the line. So, you can convert EVERY tcl programm to python (if you have the right tcl libs installed of course).

Comment: Did you mean "wrapped"? Won't change it though; "warped" suits my sense of humor. :-)

Comment: Yes, I changed it. English is not my first language :)

Answer (score 0):

[pxpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net) has a module called pxssh, that takes a lot of the the work out of manipulating simple ssh sessions. I found that this wasn't sufficient for heavy automation and wrote [remote](http://gethub.com/Telenav/python-remote) as an add-on to increase error handling.

using pxssh

```
from pxssh import pxssh
p = pxssh()
p.login('host', 'user', 'password')
p.send('command')
```

using remote

```
from remote import remote
r = remote('host', 'user', 'password')
if r.login():
  r.send('command')
```

I'm not sure about the Tkinter use case, my only assumption is that you are using it to craft a gui and there are many tutorials for it. I've used http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/ before and it compares both Tkinter and wxPython.